# Mac 上でのVSCodeにおいて、fs.mkdirSync() と fs.unlinkSync() を記述した Node.js コードをデバッグ実行すると、not permitted エラー

Tags: macos, node.js, vscode

Mac: MacOS Montery 12.3.1
VSCode: April 2022 (version 1.67)

Mac上でVSCodeを実行し、以下のコードをデバッグ実行して見たのですが、fs.mkdirSync()はエラーなく実行され、実際にフォルダが作成されるのですが、その直後にfs.unlinkSync()で `EPERM: operation not permitted` エラーとなり、フォルダが削除できません。
どのようにすれば、VSCodeのデバッグ実行でエラーを回避させることができるのでしょうか？

```
import fs from 'fs';

const documentsFolderPath = '/Users/hoge/Documents';
const hogePath = path.join(documentsFolderPath, '/hoge');

fs.mkdirSync(hogePath);
fs.unlinkSync(hogePath);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ディレクトリを削除するなら

```
fs.unlinkSync(hogePath);
```

のかわりに

```
fs.rmdirSync(hogePath);
```

とすればよいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
上手くいきました！